# How to open different pages in the same window by vb.net CefSharp

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I create control ChromiumWebBrowser1 in form1.and i open  link [www.baidu.com](http://www.baidu.com) page in ChromiumWebBrowser1.
now i find many more links in page page.I click these links again,
unfortunately These web links all open in a new pop-up window.
I don't want that. I think these links still open in the first window
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7efj.jpg)
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.Handler
Imports CefSharp.WinForms

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ChromiumWebBrowser1.Load("https://www.baidu.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing

End Sub

Private Sub bt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bt.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ChromiumWebBrowser1.Address
End Sub
```

End Class
who can help me?
Thank you.

I hope someone can realize my idea through the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is code in C#

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = new MyLifeSpanHandler();

public class MyLifeSpanHandler : CefSharp.Handler.LifeSpanHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        chromiumWebBrowser.LoadUrlAsync(targetUrl);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: here is vb.net not C# can you change code to vb.net?thank you

Comment: This answer won't compile as the `newBrowser` out param isn't assigned. `LoadUrl` should also be used instead of `LoadUrlAsync` in this scenario. I've posted an alternative answer.

Comment: @amaitland why should we use `LoadUrl` instead of `LoadUrlAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the popup and load the url in the main browser frame. There are instances were `targetUrl` will be empty, e.g. when the popup was crated programtically using `window.open`, there is no way to load those in the main frame.

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();

public class LifeSpanHandler : CefSharp.Handler.LifeSpanHandler
{
    protected override bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        newBrowser = null;
        
        // Load the Url in existing ChromiumWebBrowser
        chromiumWebBrowser.LoadUrl(targetUrl);
        
        // Return true to cancel the popup creation
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can translate this to `VB.Net` using online services like https://converter.telerik.com/